# Python - getline() method not printing "newlines"

Tags: python, getline, linecache

I am relatively new to python and I am making a small game that involves importing each line of the text from a .txt file, so that it can be printed to the user. To do this, I'm using linecache.getline() to get the specific line of the file that I want while not having the whole file stored as a list. However, if I use "\n" to create a new line, then linecache.getline() automatically inserts another backslash to "cancel" it.

For example, if in the text file I write
`\nHello`,
linecache.getline() will store it in the variable as
`\\nHello`
which prints as
`\nHello`.

Is there any way to stop this? I can post my specific code if required.

Any help with file manipulation will be appreciated since I am very new to it and thank you for looking at my question.

Comment: have you tried 
myFile = open("FILENAME", "R")
    myFile.readline("LINE NUMBER HERE")

Comment: If it’s a text file why aren’t you just putting a return between lines? \n represents a single return character, but if that appears in a text file it’s actually two characters.

Comment: `\n` only represents new line within string constants in your program, it gets converted to the single character when printed or written to a file.   Your editor doesn't do that when you created your text file.  as @Mark notes: just enter actual newlines.

Comment: @Samuel I thought that the parameter for readline() was for the amount of bytes you dedicate for the line are reading (i.e. the amount of characters)

Comment: @RufusVS I could, but when reading the lines, the empty newline won't be stored in the variable since it's a different line, so it would just print it without it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.